# Split a string by a regex without consuming the delimiter?

Tags: php

I have a string that looks like this:

`1d20+3d6-4d8+10`

I would like to split that into:

`1d20`, `+3d6`, `-4d8`, `+10`.

`preg_split()` consumes the `+` and `-` symbols. What is the best way to tell it "split at these symbols, but don't consume them."?  I can brute force a solution, but I'm guessing there's a simple solution in the PHP standard library that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Depends on how you defined these symbols, the symbol that is math operator?

Comment: Just + and -.   preg_split('/([+-])/' ....) is my current code, which does the split perfect except it consumes the + and -.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split using a zero-width forward lookahead for the delimiter (`+` or `-`):

```
$string = '1d20+3d6-4d8+10';
print_r(preg_split('/(?=[+-])/', $string));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1d20
    [1] => +3d6
    [2] => -4d8
    [3] => +10
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/piWhO)

Answer (score 1):

If you put the delimiter in a capture group, they'll be included in the `preg_split()` result, but as separate elements. So you'll get

```
["1d20", "+", "3d6", "-", "4d8", "+", "10"]
```

Another option is to use `preg_match_all()` instead of `preg_split()`, and make the operator an optional pattern at the beginning of the regexp that matches the items.

```
preg_match_all('/[-+]?[^-+]+/', $string, $matches);
```